# Codenameone FloatingHint issue

Tags: java, codenameone

Tried using the [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) `FloatingHint` class but on running the application i get an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component is already contained in Container`. This was my implementation

```
Form f = new Form(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
TextField hintTest= new TextField(11);
hintTest.setHint("The hint");
new FloatingHint(hintTest);
addComponent(hintTest);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to get it working with

```
    TextField hintTest= new TextField(11);
    hintTest.setHint("The Hint");
    FloatingHint x = new FloatingHint(uname);
    addComponent(x);
```